# How to implement AdaBoostM1 in Weka?

Tags: java, weka

I'm using Weka 3.6.13 (latest at the time of posting) and I can't seem to get AdaBoostM1 to select a classifier. I would like to include options for both [AdaBoostM1](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/AdaBoostM1.html) as well as for the base classifier. But the function setClassifier() just don't seem to exist in the JAR but is present in the Docs.

```java
import java.io.*;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.NominalPrediction;
import weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class ULCWekaTest
{

   public static Evaluation classify(Classifier model,
                                     Instances trainingSet, Instances testingSet)
      throws Exception
   {
      Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(trainingSet);

      model.buildClassifier(trainingSet);
      evaluation.evaluateModel(model, testingSet);

      return evaluation;
   }

   public static double calculateAccuracy(FastVector predictions)
   {
      double correct = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++)
      {
         NominalPrediction np = (NominalPrediction) predictions.elementAt(i);
         if(np.predicted() == np.actual())
            correct++;
      }

      return 100 * correct / predictions.size();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      String basepath =
         "/Users/Ebe/Pantheon/Ares/PhD/Course Work/MLT/MLT-Lab/Mini Project/Implementation/";

      Instances trainData;
      try(BufferedReader reader =
         new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(basepath + "train80.arff")))
      {
         trainData = new Instances(reader);
         reader.close();
      }
      trainData.setClassIndex(0);

      Instances testData;
      try(BufferedReader reader =
         new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(basepath + "test80.arff")))
      {
         testData = new Instances(reader);
         reader.close();
      }
      testData.setClassIndex(0);

      Classifier forest, adaboost;
      String[] options = new String[2];

      for(int i = 100; i < 500; i+=2)
      {
         for(int s = 6; s <= 6; s++)
         {
            adaboost = new AdaBoostM1();
            forest = new RandomForest();
            //for(String str : forest.getOptions())
               // System.out.println(str);   
            options[0] = "-I";
            options[1] = ""+i;
            forest.setOptions(options);

            options[0] = "-S";
            options[1] = "" + s;
            forest.setOptions(options);

            adaboost.setClassifier(forest); // <-- COMPILER ERROR AT THIS POINT
            // Collect every group of predictions for current model in a FastVector
            FastVector predictions = new FastVector();
            // For each training-testing split pair, train and test the classifier
            Evaluation validation =
               classify(adaboost, trainData, testData);
            predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());

            // Calculate overall accuracy of current classifier on all splits
            double accuracy = calculateAccuracy(predictions);
         // Print current classifier's name and accuracy in a complicated,
            // but nice-looking way.
            System.out.println("-I " + i + " -S " + s + ": " + String.format(
               "%.2f%%", accuracy));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this? Could anyone please explain or at least provide a link to a sample AdaBoostM1-Weka code in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Classifier` class was being used. This is a base class of the `AdaBoostM1` and `RandomForest` classifier. Hence you would not have access to the `selectClassifier()` method as it is from a class derived from `Classifier`.

Changing this line

```
Classifier forest, adaboost;
```

to

```
Classifier forest;
AdaBoostM1 adaboost;
```

solved the problem.